# django : unable to call a python function by clicking submit button

Tags: python, django

Trying to call Installation function when we click a submit button on HTML Page and taking the data from HTML only,i am new to django.
Help me out..!

Views File:

```
from .forms import Details
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from . import installation

def output(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        details=Details(request.POST)
        if details.is_valid():
            Obj=details.cleaned_data
            path=Obj['Path']
            device_type=Obj['Device']
            image_version=Obj['Version']
            return installation()
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

App/urls.py File:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',views.output,{'template_name':'home_page.html'}),
]
```

Forms.py File :

```
from django import forms

class Details(forms.Form):
    Device=forms.CharField(required=True, label='Device_Type', max_length=32)
    Path=forms.FileField(required=True, label='Path_to_install_build')
    Version=forms.CharField(required=True, label='Version_type',max_length=32)
```

Comment: Where is the logic of *clicking*?

Comment: Hi Willem,

<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your HTML? if your frontend (HTML) is not reaching your backend at your views, probabily your action is not right, so check if your form have the right action

```
<form action="/" method="POST"> 
   {% csrf_token %} 
   <!-- Rest of the HTML code to your form -->
   <input type="submit">Submit</input>    
</form>
```

Im setting you action to `/` because you using root path to your views, if you change it to like detail, the action should be `/detail/`

BTW you can use the built-in form from django

```
 {% csrf_token %} 
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type="submit">Submit</input>
```

Comment: nice, please mask as answer ;D